# Mac OS Mojave 10.14.1 File Sharing services off after restart

Tags: command-line, mojave, file-sharing

I have a late 2014 Mac Mini, running Mojave 10.14.1, which I'm using as a file server to a few users in our lab.  The server will occasionally see power outages due to weather.

The machine reliably restarts after power outages, but the "File Sharing" service is deactivated.

1. Is there a way to reliably start the File Sharing service, at boot time?
2. Does anyone know of a work-around, to activate the service from the command line? Ideally, I'd like to script a check -> inspect the service state, and start it if it's not running. 
   I'd use "cron" to run the check every so often, unless someone has a better recommendation.

Comment: Removed the applescript tag, added by @wch1zpink. I don't necessarily need an applescript solution, I need an automated solution that can be made to run at startup (not login). Could be bash, python, whatever.

Comment: You said, "The server will occasionally see power outages due to weather.", well how long are the power outages? Is the Mac mini plugged into a UPS Battery Backup? If it's not, it should be.

Comment: I am experiencing the same fault on 10.14.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to macOS Mojave 10.14.3.  Looks like Apple has fixed this bug.

Anyone else having this problem: update to 10.14.3 or later.